# How to find client signal strength from the Rpi command line?

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+

I have a network made of Rpi, ubiquities, and esp8266. Raspberry pi is configured as the eth0 to eth1 router. Eth1 is made using a USB to ethernet converter. The Main ubiquiti is connected to the eth1 using the ethernet cable and the same generate a hotspot "RpiAP". All the esp8266 is connected to the Hotspot RpiAP.

The ubiquiti is configured from another laptop and I don't have access to the laptop.

I need to check the signal strength received at each esp8266. From a web search, we have software to check the signal strength from the client-side. But here, I can't access the esp8266. I have only access to the Raspberry Pi.

How do I know the esp8266 receives a good signal? Is there any way to check the same using command line?

Comment: Since the ESPs are connected to the Rpi AP, why don't you just *ask them* (eg. via UDP)?

Comment: I don't get you? How we can understand the strength via UDP?

Comment: **The ESP can check the signal strength itself** -- isn't that the best source?  So my point is you could implement a simple UDP based server on the ESP to provide that information and the Pi can get it from there.  Very possibly someone has already done something like this.  But you might not even have to do that if you can automate a login .  I have not done much with an ESP in a long time, I dunno how easy that would be.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have access to any device except the RasPi the only way I see is to use another portable device with a WiFi connection and preferred Linux Operating System, for example a second Raspberry Pi or a Laptop. Then you can walk to the location of a **esp8266** and measure the signal strength. You can use the `iw`, for example:

```
~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep -B5 'SSID: RpiAP'
        freq: 2462
        beacon interval: 100 TUs
        capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1431)
        signal: -52.00 dBm
        last seen: 0 ms ago
        SSID: RpiAP
--
        freq: 5500
        beacon interval: 100 TUs
        capability: ESS Privacy SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime RadioMeasure (0x1511)
        signal: -56.00 dBm
        last seen: 0 ms ago
        SSID: RpiAP
```